# Get DocuSign SignTags to RichTextbox before Signing Ceremony

Tags: richtextbox, docusignapi

Can i get the DocuSign Tags(Sign,Initials, Datetime) into RichTextbox(Devexpress) before signing ceremony. ie After send sign request can i get the document with all sign templates from DocuSign before sign in complete. Now i can send the document for Sign in and get the envelopeId.  So can i get the document in RichTextbox with all Sign tags from docusign before signing ceremony.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [listEnvelopeRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/) api with the query parameter `include_tabs=true`to retrieve the list of tabs.

> GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients?include_tabs=true